# Why does this LINQPad Util.Cmd() call fail?

Tags: c#, command, linqpad, util.cmd

I'm trying to execute the Windows find command from LINQPad but it isn't working and I don't understand why. This is my LINQPad script and I'm executing it in LINQPad as C# Statement(s).

```
string find = @"find ""Processing request to "" ""Y:\Services\DynaMiX.Services.DatabaseMaintenance\*.log""";
find.Dump("find");
var results = Util.Cmd(find);
results.Dump();
```

The `find.Dump("find")` statement displays the following as expected.

```
find "Processing request to " "Y:\Services\SteveC.Services.DatabaseMaintenance\*.log"
```

When I copy that and paste it in a CMD window it executes the find as it should but when running the script in LINQPad it throws CommandExecutionException with the ErrorText **FIND: Parameter format not correct**.

Can anyone shed any light on why this might happen?

Comment: You might need to double terminate your backslashes.

Comment: No, it's a literal string, but I tried it anyway and it still works in CMD window with double slashes but LINQPad error is the same.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out to be an incorrect use of Util.Cmd on my part. Instead of `Util.Cmd(string commandText)` I needed to use the `Util.Cmd(string commandText, string args)` overload. The following statement works.

```
var results = Util.Cmd("find", @"""Processing request to "" ""Y:\Services\SteveC.Services.DatabaseMaintenance\*.log""");
```